# What was the inspiration for the creation of the League of Assassins?

Tags: dc, comics, batman, inspiration

What was the inspiration for Denny O'Neil and Neal Adams in creating the League of Assassins?

Comment: The Assassins? No, seriously, the Assassins (the Asāsiyyūn) already were a fanatical sect of killers, at least in the popular imagination, so they didn't need to look too far. Giving the leader the Arabic name R'as al-Ghul only confirms the connection.

Comment: Andof course the name R'as al Ghul is very sinister.  A ghoul (Arabic: غول, ghūl) is a demon-like being or monstrous humanoid. The concept originated in pre-Islamic Arabian religion, [1] associated with graveyards and the consumption of human flesh. Modern fiction often uses the term to label a certain kind of undead monster.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghoul