# Is there a connection between Dennis O’Neil’s League of Assassins and the hashashin?

Tags: dc, batman, inspiration

Are there quotes and interviews from Dennis O’Neil on the inspiration for the creation of the League of Assassins? It is said that they were inspired by a real order of assassins — which I believe, because in their appearance in *Detective Comics* #405, they used similar daggers to that of [the Hashashin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_Assassins).

But for more evidence, has Dennis O’Neil ever confirmed that he based the League of Assassins on these real assassins?

Comment: This is a probable duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/269818/what-was-the-inspiration-for-the-creation-of-the-league-of-assassins.

Comment: No that asks the inspiration behind the league I’m asking the interview where Dannis O’Neil confirmed the claim of the hashashin there is a difference

Comment: "It is said that they were inspired by the real order of assassins" _[citation needed]_

Comment: "No that asks the inspiration behind the league I’m asking the interview where Dannis O’Neil confirmed the claim of the hashashin there is a difference" — so that question asks what the inspiration was, and your question asks whether the inspiration was the Hashashin. An answer for that question would answer yours, which might means that [it counts as a duplicate on this site](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates).